# Idiomatic way to talk to REST backend from a Scala.js frontend?

Tags: scala.js

I wrote a SPA with Scala.js, where I use a library called [RosHTTP](https://github.com/hmil/RosHTTP) in
order to communicate with a REST backend.  It helps me add query
parameters, set headers, work with cookies and increase transfer
limits for very large responses from the backend, amongst other
features. It lets me conveniently define handlers for success, error, etc.

Now, that library is no longer maintained, and when I look around the
Internet, I find no real replacements for it.  I have therefore started using
the API from `scalajs.dom`, `XMLHttpRequest`, but that API is very
basic.  For example, how do you handle cookies?  How do you add query
parameters to POST requests, etc.?

My question therefore is: how do other Scala.js developers solve this
problem?  It seems to me that most libraries in one form or another
facade an underlying JavaScript library (RosHTTP did that,
`scalajs-io/request` does it to give another example), which offers these types of convenience
calls that I'm talking about.  But none of the examples, I mentioned
is still maintained and up to date.  Am I to write yet another,
personal facade, am I to work with the `XMLHttpRequest`-type API I
mentioned above?

I'd be very curious, if there exists a kind-of idomatic way to connect
a Scala.js frontend with a REST backend, without re-inventing the
wheel.

Comment: Have you looked at sttp? See an intro here: https://docs.scala-lang.org/toolkit/http-client-request.html (that article is for the JVM, but sttp also offers a Scala.js API).

Comment: Thank you very much, not sure how I missed this particular one. Would you also happen to know why on both introductory examples (versions 3.9 as well as 4) I get an error like: `not found: value DefaultSyncBackend`, despite prior `import sttp.client4._`? (`DefaultFutureBackend` is available, for example.)

Comment: I just got a response to my follow-up question on Discord: in all likelyhood `DefaultSyncBackend` is simply JVM-only and not available for JavaScript (which makes sense, considering how JavaScript works). Someone also pointed out another library called http4s-dom, which I'm going to have a look at. With those two choices, I think, this question can be considered as answered. (A shame that RosHTTP never got anywhere. That library was an absolute marvel, had everything one needed.)